Bug: `Apache2` with `PHP-FPM` picks the wrong pool
I have configured PHP and Apache so that a separate PHP-FPM pool is created for each user in a multihost system.
The web panel runs in its own pool with different rights.
Administrations-WebPanel
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # CONFIG
    Define DOMAIN       my.fruit
    Define SOCKET       /run/php/panel.sock
    Define ROOT         /etc/fruithost/panel/
    
    # DO NOT EDIT
    ServerAdmin     support@${DOMAIN}
    DocumentRoot    ${ROOT}
    ServerName      ${DOMAIN}
    ErrorLog        "/var/fruithost/logs/panel_error.log" 
    CustomLog       "/var/fruithost/logs/panel_access.log" combined
    CustomLog       "/var/fruithost/logs/panel_bandwidth.log" common
    
    # Security
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId www-data www-data
    </IfModule>
    
    # Debug-Mode
    #ProxyErrorOverride Off
    #ServerSignature    On
    #LogLevel       debug
        
    <IfModule headers>
        Header set X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # Define Error Pages
        Alias /errors/100.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/100.html
        Alias /errors/101.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/101.html
        Alias /errors/401.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/401.html
        Alias /errors/403.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/403.html
        Alias /errors/404.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/404.html
        Alias /errors/405.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/405.html
        Alias /errors/408.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/408.html
        Alias /errors/410.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/410.html
        Alias /errors/411.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/411.html
        Alias /errors/412.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/412.html
        Alias /errors/413.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/413.html
        Alias /errors/414.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/414.html
        Alias /errors/415.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/415.html
        Alias /errors/500.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/500.html
        Alias /errors/501.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/501.html
        Alias /errors/502.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/502.html
        Alias /errors/503.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/503.html
        Alias /errors/504.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/504.html
        Alias /errors/505.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/505.html
        Alias /errors/506.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/506.html
        
        # Define Modules-URL
        Alias /app /etc/fruithost/modules
        
        # Define Theme-URL
        Alias /theme /etc/fruithost/themes
    </IfModule>

    # PHP-FPM
    <IfModule !mod_php8.c>
        <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
            
            # Forward Auth-Header
            <IfModule setenvif_module>
                SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
            </IfModule>
            
            # Define Proxy
            <Proxy "unix:${SOCKET}|fcgi://panel">
                ProxySet disablereuse=on
            </Proxy>
            
            # When .php-Files will be visited
            <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                # Remove old handlers (if exists)
                RemoveHandler       .php
                
                ProxyFCGIBackendType FPM
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" DOCUMENT_ROOT "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"                                
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_INFO "%{PATH_INFO}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_TRANSLATED "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{reqenv:PATH_INFO}%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
                #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" REQUEST_URI "${REQUEST_URI}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_NAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_FILENAME}"
                
                SetHandler proxy:fcgi://panel
            </FilesMatch>
            
            # Debug Status
            <LocationMatch "/fh-panel-status">
                ProxyPass "unix:${SOCKET}|fcgi://panel/fh-panel-status"
            </LocationMatch>
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    
    # Accessibility
    <Directory /etc/fruithost/panel>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /etc/fruithost/themes>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /etc/fruithost/modules>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

[panel]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/$pool.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0770
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
process.dumpable = yes
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.status_path = /fh-panel-status
slowlog = /var/fruithost/logs/$pool_slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 1m
;request_slowlog_trace_depth = 20
decorate_workers_output = yes
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/fruithost/logs/php_error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

User
# Generated by fruithost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # DO NOT EDIT
    ServerAdmin     abuse@domain.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain.com/
    ServerName      domain.com
    ErrorLog        /var/fruithost/users/admin/logs/domain.com_error.log
    CustomLog       /var/fruithost/users/admin/logs/domain.com_access.log combined
    CustomLog       /var/fruithost/users/admin/logs/domain.com_bandwidth.log common


    # Security
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId admin www-data
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # Define Error Pages
        Alias /errors/100.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/100.html
        Alias /errors/101.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/101.html
        Alias /errors/400.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/400.html
        Alias /errors/401.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/401.html
        Alias /errors/403.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/403.html
        Alias /errors/404.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/404.html
        Alias /errors/405.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/405.html
        Alias /errors/408.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/408.html
        Alias /errors/410.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/410.html
        Alias /errors/411.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/411.html
        Alias /errors/412.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/412.html
        Alias /errors/413.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/413.html
        Alias /errors/414.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/414.html
        Alias /errors/415.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/415.html
        Alias /errors/500.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/500.html
        Alias /errors/501.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/501.html
        Alias /errors/502.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/502.html
        Alias /errors/503.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/503.html
        Alias /errors/504.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/504.html
        Alias /errors/505.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/505.html
        Alias /errors/506.html /etc/fruithost/placeholder/errors/506.html
    </IfModule>

    # PHP-FPM
    <IfModule !mod_php8.c>
        <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
            # Forward Auth-Header
            <IfModule setenvif_module>
                SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
            </IfModule>

            # Define Proxy
            <Proxy "unix:/var/fruithost/users/.sockets/admin.sock|fcgi://user-admin">
                ProxySet disablereuse=on
            </Proxy>

            # When .php-Files will be visited
            <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                # Remove old handlers (if exists)
                RemoveHandler       .php
                
                ProxyFCGIBackendType FPM
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" DOCUMENT_ROOT "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_INFO "%{PATH_INFO}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_TRANSLATED "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{reqenv:PATH_INFO}%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
                #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" REQUEST_URI "${REQUEST_URI}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_NAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
                ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_FILENAME}"
                
                SetHandler proxy:fcgi://user-admin
            </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    

    # Accessibility
    <Directory /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain.com/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Files ~ "(^(?!\.fruithost)\.|php\.ini)">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>

[admin]
prefix = /var/fruithost/users/$pool

user = $pool
group = www-data

listen = /var/fruithost/users/.sockets/$pool.sock

listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

process.dumpable = yes
decorate_workers_output = yes
catch_workers_output = yes

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

;chroot = /
chdir = /

;access.log = log/$pool.access.log
decorate_workers_output = yes
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = logs/php_error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_value[session.save_path] = temp/
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/fruithost/users/$pool

What is the problem?
All user/domain configurations always have the same scheme.
When I restart the PHP-FPM service, everything is displayed correctly when I call up a domain (PHP-Info is ok and openbasedir restrictions are also used correctly).
However, when I now call the webpanel (my.fruit), Apache selects the PHP-FPM pool panel as specified in the configuration. After trying to call a domain (for example example.com), Apache no longer uses the defined PHP-FPM pool, but that of the panel and therefore no longer has any openbasedir registrations.
What am I doing wrong?
Why is a different PHP-FPM pool suddenly being used?

The Problem is not PHP-FPM or Apache2.
The Problem is Opcache.
We can fix the problem with following additional PHP-Flags (or php.ini-Directives):
; Opcache
php_admin_flag[opcache.enable] = 1
php_admin_flag[opcache.validate_permission] = 1
php_admin_value[opcache.restrict_api] = /var/fruithost/users/$pool

